# How to get SHA1 key in my Windows I tried many ways but no use

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm not able to get SHA1 key for Firebase project. How can I do that? I'm using Angular.

I tried this one:

`keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-for-debug-mode-in-android-studio-c9df7ae2401b) will help.

Comment: What was the output of the statement you used?  (The only comment you did get in the last two days suggest doing about the same as you did. The only change I can think of is not using the backslash after `-v`)